Meaning of "non constraint envelope signal"
I am studying signal processing. In the power amplifier theory and its affect on satellite system I have found the following:

Compared to the conventional terrestrial system, non-terrestrial radio
links are more critical for power efficiency (PE) of power amplifier
(HPA), which causes more nonlinear distortion when a
non-constraint-envelop signal passes through HPA...

Do I understand correctly that the envelope represents the amplitude? If so, does a non-constraint -envelope signal mean an amplitude-varying signal?
EDIT
Y. Li, X. Gu, L. DAN, R. He, X. Mao and Y. Xiao, "Improved OFDM Waveform for Radio Link in Non-terrestrial Network,"


"non-constraint"? It should be "non-constant", as you wrote in your last sentence.

can you cite your source please? Context might greatly increase the likelihood we that we can help you.

If, indeed you meant to say "non-constant" and not "non-constraint" then you should edit your question.  Whatever "non-constraint" is, it doesn't mean the same thing as "non-constant".

@MarcusMüller I have added a screenshot and the title of the article

I feel like that is a typo

The English proficiency in that excerpt is very poor.  If the rest of the paper is similarly bad, I would not use that paper for learning about a subject.  It will only confuse someone not already familiar with the subject matter.
